# jquery DatePicker buttonimage is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquerydatepicker. But the button image is not showing at all. What may be the problem?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$('#<%= TextBoxFromDate.ClientID  %>').datepicker({ changeYear: true, yearRange: '-20', showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/css/images/icon_cal.png", showAnim: 'slide',
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

EDIT : my image is in rootfolder/css/images folder. and my masterpage is in rootfolder/master folder. I am using datepicker on the master page. Even '../css/images/icon_cal.png' is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that you are providing the correct url to the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change *ui-lightness* with skin you have chosen.

```
css/ui-lightness/images/icon_cal.png
```